# Graphviz ordering of nodes on the same rank

Tags: graphviz, dot

I made a graph and it looks like I want it to with one exception: the cluster containing nodes `D` and `E` should be placed between nodes `B` and `C`.

[image]

Here is the `.dot`:

```
digraph {
  node[shape=rectangle]
  graph [
        newrank=true
    ];

  Z
  A
  B
  C

  {
    rank=same;
    A -> B -> D;
    D -> C[style=invis];
  }

  subgraph clusterSS {
    style=dashed;
    D[group=ss]
    E[group=ss]
    D -> E[style="dashed"; dir = none];
  }

  Z -> A
  Z -> B
  Z -> D
  Z -> C
  A -> P[dir = back]
  B -> S
  S -> B[constraint = false];

  C -> S
  S -> E[constraint = false]
  E -> S[label = "Label"]
}
```

I expected that having edges between nodes

> ```
>   {
>     rank=same;
>     A -> B -> D;
>     D -> C[style=invis];
>   }
> ```

would ensure correct ordering, but it doesn't.

The ordering becomes correct once I delete the edge label between `S` and `E`, but I do need to keep the labels.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[non-trivial, not guaranteed to work as desired in any other circumstance]
Added clusters, invisible nodes,and more.  ugh

```
digraph {
  node[shape=rectangle]
  graph [
        newrank=true
    ];

  {
    rank=same;
    A -> B -> D;
    D -> C[style=invis];
  }

  subgraph clusterSS {
    style=dashed;
    D [group=ss]
    E [group=ss]
    D -> E[style="dashed"; dir = none];
  }
  subgraph clusterAP {
    peripheries=0
    A -> P[dir = back]
  }
  subgraph clusterB {
    peripheries=0
    B
    bogus    [style=invis shape=plain]
    B->bogus [style=invis]
  }

  Z -> A
  Z -> B
  Z -> D
  Z -> C

  S [group=ss]

  B -> S:nw
  B -> S:w [dir=back]  
  
  C -> S
  S -> E[constraint = false]
  E -> S[label = "Label"]
}
```

Giving:
[image]